# Adjust matplotlib colorbar position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to place a label on top of a colorbar. Drawing the label works fine, but the final position adjustment of the colorbar axis is not working. It seems like the call to "set_position" simply does nothing. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Plot some sample data.
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1, 10, 0.1), np.arange(1, 10, 0.1))
Z = np.sin(X) ** 2 + np.cos(Y) ** 2
plt.pcolor(X, Y, Z)
# Add the colorbar.
cb = plt.colorbar(shrink=0.8)
cax = cb.ax
# Add label on top of colorbar.
cb.ax.set_xlabel("mylabel")
cb.ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
cb.ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.8, 1.05)
# Adjust colorbar position (NOT working).
pos1 = cax.get_position()
yshift = pos1.height * 0.05 / 0.8
pos2 = [pos1.x0, pos1.y0 - yshift, pos1.width, pos1.height]
cax.set_position(pos2)
# Adjust and show the plot.
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. The `yshift` you use is rather small, so an effect my not be directly obvious.
2. Calling `plt.tight_layout()` rearranges the axes, and thus overwrites the position you have set.

So you would probably want to first call `plt.tight_layout()` and afterwards change the position.

Comment: You hit the nail on your second point; it was indeed the 'plt.tight_layout()' call which reverted the manual positioning.